# WooCommerce Force Display of Base Country Order Addresses

Tags: plugins

It seems in recent versions of WooCommerce that the base country does not show on the order screens.

Ex. we have 2 orders, one being from Australia and one from the United States. In the WooCommerce --> Orders screen the Australian order doesn't say Australia at the end of the order billing and shipping addresses (because our base location is Australia). The international orders do show the country though.

How can that be fixed so that the base country is being shown in the formatted addresses still?

Answer (score 3):

[Looking through the code](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/7fda2bd832d9f85b142b5b789e695a4c55f79167/includes/class-wc-countries.php#L643) it looks like this is intended functionality to reduce the clutter in the admin screen. Here's a little snippet so you can override that functionality.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_formatted_address_force_country_display', '__return_true' );
```

This only works in the bleeding edge version of WooCommerce - it should be included in 2.0.14

Gist permalink - https://gist.github.com/BFTrick/6241267

Comment: Works perfectly. You could also expand it to use an option which is stored in the database, which would allow you to turn it on or off via phpMyAdmin instead of editing the file on a live site:
`
add_filter( 'woocommerce_formatted_address_force_country_display', function() {
 return 'yes' == get_option('formatted_address_force_country_display', 'yes');
} );
`